# Could someone help me with this XML code?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

Given the following HTML, JavaScript, and XML, what does

```
    tempText.innerHTML = allImages[i].textContent
```

mean, and what is the value of

```
    allImages[i].textContent
```

---

#### HTML markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Second Ajax Script</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="script02.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script02.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pictureBar"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript code

```
window.onload = initAll;
var xhr = false;

function initAll() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) { }
        }
    }

    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = showPictures;
        xhr.open("GET", "C:\wamp\www\flickrfeed.xml", true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, but I couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest");
    }
}

function showPictures() {
    var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var tempText = document.createElement("div");
            
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var allImages = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("content");

            for (var i=0; i<allImages.length; i++) {
                tempText.innerHTML = allImages[i].textContent;
                tempDiv = tempText.getElementsByTagName("p");

                var theText = tempDiv[1].innerHTML;
                theText = theText.replace(/240/g,"75");
                theText = theText.replace(/180/g,"75");
                theText = theText.replace(/_m/g,"_s");
                document.getElementById("pictureBar").innerHTML += theText;
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("There was a problem with the request " + xhr.status);
        }
    }
}
```

#### XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"  xmlns:flickr="urn:flickr:" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">    
    <title>Content from Paradise Ridge Sculpture Grove</title>
    <link rel="self" href="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157600976524175&amp;nsid=23922109@N00&amp;lang=en-us" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/sets/72157600976524175"/>
    <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:http://www.flickr.com/photos/23922109@N00/sets/72157600976524175</id>
    <icon>http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1335/882568164_72eee9b41f_s.jpg</icon>
    <subtitle>The &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.paradiseridgewinery.com/&quot;&gt;Paradise Ridge Winery&lt;/a&gt; not only has great wines, but they also have a sculpture garden. We visited on 22 July 2007.</subtitle>
    <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
    <generator uri="http://www.flickr.com/">Flickr</generator>        
    <entry>
        <title>IMG_0045.JPG</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882590644/in/set-72157600976524175/"/>
        <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/882590644/in/set-72157600976524175</id>
        <published>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</published>
        <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
        <dc:date.Taken>2007-07-22T13:42:49-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
        <content type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882590644/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0045.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1063/882590644_5a4a0d89f3_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;240&quot; height=&quot;180&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0045.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;          
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>Dori Smith</name>
            <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1063/882590644_5a4a0d89f3_m.jpg" />    
        <category term="winery" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sonomacounty" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="dorismith" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridge" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridgesculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>IMG_0043.JPG</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882589162/in/set-72157600976524175/"/>
        <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/882589162/in/set-72157600976524175</id>
        <published>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</published>
        <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
        <dc:date.Taken>2007-07-22T13:41:55-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
        <content type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882589162/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0043.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1179/882589162_25b4d6bcbe_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;180&quot; height=&quot;240&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0043.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>Dori Smith</name>
            <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1179/882589162_25b4d6bcbe_m.jpg" />    
        <category term="winery" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sonomacounty" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="dorismith" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridge" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridgesculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>IMG_0042.JPG</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882587910/in/set-72157600976524175/"/>
        <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/882587910/in/set-72157600976524175</id>
        <published>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</published>
        <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
        <dc:date.Taken>2007-07-22T13:40:36-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
        <content type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882587910/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0042.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1073/882587910_39ffde28e6_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;240&quot; height=&quot;180&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0042.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>Dori Smith</name>
            <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1073/882587910_39ffde28e6_m.jpg" />    
        <category term="winery" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sonomacounty" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="dorismith" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridge" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridgesculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>IMG_0041.JPG</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882586288/in/set-72157600976524175/"/>
        <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/882586288/in/set-72157600976524175</id>
        <published>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</published>
        <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
        <dc:date.Taken>2007-07-22T13:40:18-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
        <content type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882586288/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0041.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1334/882586288_6de3304bbb_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;240&quot; height=&quot;180&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0041.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>Dori Smith</name>
            <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1334/882586288_6de3304bbb_m.jpg" />    
        <category term="winery" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sonomacounty" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="dorismith" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridge" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridgesculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>IMG_0040.JPG</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882583896/in/set-72157600976524175/"/>
        <id>tag:flickr.com,2005:/photo/882583896/in/set-72157600976524175</id>
        <published>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</published>
        <updated>2007-07-24T05:19:08Z</updated>
        <dc:date.Taken>2007-07-22T13:39:49-08:00</dc:date.Taken>
        <content type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882583896/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0040.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1233/882583896_90fad7b9ea_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;180&quot; height=&quot;240&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0040.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>Dori Smith</name>
            <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1233/882583896_90fad7b9ea_m.jpg" />  
        <category term="winery" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sonomacounty" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="sculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="dorismith" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridge" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
        <category term="paradiseridgesculptures" scheme="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/" />
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Sadly, stackoverflow does not overquoting penalties.

Comment: The code in this question is taken from *JavaScript & Ajax for the Web, Visual QuickStart Guide, 7th Edition*. I am the primary author of the book. Since the code is clearly explained, line by line, in the book, I conclude that you are a student who is asking other people to do your homework for you. That's academically lazy, at best, and at the least is just not cool. I further note that in this particular example, you copied code containing the name of my coauthor, which is just head-slappingly clumsy and made it easy to bring your actions to my attention.

Answer (score 3):

Given that this is straight out of *JavaScript & Ajax for the Web: Visual QuickStart Guide, 7th edition*<sup>1</sup>, what in particular are you having trouble with in the (line-by-line) explanation on pages 329-335?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Co-written by me, btw.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) contains (surprize!) the text content of the node, e.g., its content with all tags stripped.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the value of content.textContent?

<content type="html">&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/people/dorismith/&quot;&gt;Dori Smith&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.flickr.com/photos/dorismith/882590644/&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0045.JPG&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1063/882590644_5a4a0d89f3_m.jpg&quot; width=&quot;240&quot; height=&quot;180&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0045.JPG&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

</content>

Comment: Why don't you use js debugger for that? There's one in every modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

.innerHTML means, the HTML within the target element.

for example

Hello World!

the .innerHTML for the element

is 'Hello World!'.

I don't understand the rest of your query though.

Although I believe that .textContent could mean the textual content with the XML node